# AF Space subsets

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X, \tau)$ be the [Arens-Fort space](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Category:Arens-Fort_Space). If we pick $X$ \ $\{0,0\}$, can we say $X$ \ $\{0,0\}$ is sequentially closed but not closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main fact you need: there is no sequence $(x_n)$ in Arens-Fort space such that $x_n \neq (0,0)$ for all $n$, that converges to $(0,0)$, so $(0,0)$ is not in the sequential closure of $A:= X\setminus \{(0,0)\}$. So indeed $A$ is not closed, but it does equal its sequential closure, so is sequentially closed.

Comment: This is what I was thinking... And this is also an example where nets are useful to characterize the closure of a set... thank you very much for the feedback!